# GNOME Night Light stops working closer to midnight

Tags: gnome

I have been using Ubuntu since the start of the year now, and I've had this issue since but have avoided asking until now. As stated in the title, the GNOME Night Light extension stops working when the time gets closer to midnight. It sometimes restores at midnight on the dot, sometimes a little later (like 0030). I've checked the dconf editor and its settings by making sure that it is on manual mode and such, but have had no success in fixing the issue. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled it but no success either.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I have perfectly same issue. I notice it from around 23:00 and usually right after midnight it hits regular night light level. I've edited `dconf` entries `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color` to manual schedule starting from `0` and ending at `24`

Comment: It starts slightly at `23:00` and reaches full color at `23:59`